# Property 'toDoItem' not found on object of type 'XYZAddToDoItemViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I am trying to follow this tutorial at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/RoadMapiOS.pdf

I was able to follow the instructions and got the suggested results but I am getting the error on "Add New Items" starting from pg 105.  I got the app to browse existing results and respond to cancel and done button to go to another view.

I am getting error on these two methods:
in 
 XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m

-semantic issue
 Property toDoItem not found on object of type 'XYZAddToDoItemViewController *'

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
       if(sender != self.doneButton) return;

     if(self.textField.text.length > 0){
     self.toDoItem = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
      self.toDoItem.itemName=self.textField.text;
      self.toDoItem.completed= NO;
  }

}
```

And this method in XYZToDoListViewController.m

semantic issuse
Error: Property 'toDoItem' not found on object of type 'XYZAddToDoItemViewController *'

However, if I change the  XYZAddToDoItemViewController to XYZToDoListViewController this error goes away.

```
-(IBAction) unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
  XYZAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];

    XYZToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
 if(item != nil){

      [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}

}
```

I have never tried Objective-C programming before so please excuse my silly mistakes. Here is the link to my project folder 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6jjzjs45opcbyon/1A2EmCakJe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `XYZAddToDoItemViewController` to have the `@property (nonatomic) XYZToDoItem *toDoItem;` in it's header file.

Comment: I got few errors with this: 1) ToDoList/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m:33:22: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: 2) ToDoList/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m:33:20: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'XYZToDoItem *'

3) ToDoList/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h:13:24: Unknown type name 'XYZToDoItem'

Comment: I got rid of the first error by declaring the property in the method file (XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m) of XYZAddToDoItemViewController instead of (XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h) file but the second error persisted. I also changed"XYZAddToDoItemViewController to XYZToDoListViewController" in XYZToDoListViewController.m as I mentioned in question. Now it works as Intended.Thanks for helping to go in the right direction.